# MySQL Query Update Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, multiple-tables

I have a contact management system and an sql dump of my contacts with five or six columns of data in it I want to import into three specific tables. Wondering what the best way to go about this is.  I have already uploaded the sql dump...its a single table now in in my contact management database.

The tables in the crm require in the companies table only the contactID...and in the songs table:

- companyID,
- contactID,
- date added (not required) and
- notes (not required)

Then there is the third table, the contact table which only requires contactname.

I have already uploaded data to each of the three tables (not sure if my order is correct on this) but now need to update and match the data in the fourth table (originally the sql dump) with the other three and update everything with its unique identifier.

Table Structures:

```
+DUMP_CONTACTS

id <<< I dont need this ID, the IDs given to each row in the CRM are the important ones.

contact_name

company

year

event_name

event_description

====Destination Tables====

+++CONTACTS TABLE++

*contactID < primary key

*contact_name

+++COMPANIES TABLE+++

*companyID < primary key

*name

*contact_ID

*year

++++Events++++
*EventID < primary key

*companyID

*contactID

*eventname

*description
```

Comment: Not sure what to try exactly...I now have a contactID and ContactName in the contacts table. However not sure how I would get get contactID into the companies table without using the fourth table my original contacts where on? I suppose I could add another column to the contacts table for companyname but even if...where would I go from there. Seems like MATCHAGAINST may need to be used/learned?  Any help with a query here would be simply awesome.

Comment: Could you try modifying your post and include the table structures of the source and destination tables.. and indicate which column should go where, as well as the relationships between tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are parts of your post that I still don't understand, so I'm going to give you SQL and then you can run them in a testing environment and we can take it from there and/or go back and start again:

```sql
-- Populate CONTACTS_TABLE with contact_name from uploaded dump
INSERT INTO CONTACTS_TABLE (contact_name)
SELECT contact_name FROM DUMP_CONTACTS

-- Populate COMPANIES with information from both CONTACTS_TABLE + dump
INSERT INTO COMPANIES (name, contact_ID, year)
SELECT d.company, c.contactID, d.year
FROM DUMP_CONTACTS AS d
    INNER JOIN CONTACTS_TABLE AS c
    ON d.contact_name = c.contact_name

-- Populate SONGS_TABLE with info from COMPANIES
INSERT INTO SONGS_TABLE (companyID, contactID)
SELECT cm.companyID, cm.contact_ID
FROM COMPANIES AS cm

-- Populate Events with info from COMPANIES + dump
INSERT INTO Events (companyID, contactID, eventname, description)
SELECT cm.companyID, cm.contact_ID, d.event_name, d.event_description
FROM DUMP_CONTACTS AS d
    INNER JOIN COMPANIES AS cm
    ON d.company = cm.name
```

I first populate `CONTACTS_TABLE` and then, since the `contactID` is required for records in `COMPANIES`, insert records from `CONTACTS_TABLE` joining the dump. `SONGS_TABLE` takes data directly from `COMPANIES`, and lastly the `Events` gets its data by joining `COMPANIES` and the dump.

Comment: Thanks...I was able to put it together. Just posted another question though if you have time to look. I am now dealing with the final query above killing mysql.